# ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 Is there an IDP example written in ASP.NET? (NOT .net CORE)

Tags: saml

I am looking at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.

We have an existing application, we need to provide SSO to other service providers. We need to be the IDP.

Is there an example written in ASP.NET MVC using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2?

I am new.

There is a NET Core example. But I am not familiar with CORE.